# Problem setting MaxHeight for Silverlight Toolkit AccordionItem 

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I'm trying to set up an Accordion that has three items.  The first two expand to pre-defined heights, and the third expands to fill all remaining space; I thought this would be easy.

Here's a dummy version of what I'm trying to do.  The accordion itself has a red background, and each of the items has its own color.  The first two items expand appropriately to their size, but if either item 1 or 2 is open, item 3 no longer expands to fill all remaining space, but either sizes too small, leaving a big chunk of red, or too big, shooting off the bottom of the screen, eclipsing the tiny sliver of red that should still be present.

Is this a bug?

I tried working around this by using two accordions, one with the two items with max heights, and a second accordion that would expand to fill all remaining height, but I could never manage to get the layout right, as I'm guessing is obvious to you Silverlight experts.

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Here's the complete code - also, note that I tried using the Height attribute instead of MaxHeight, but that just caused the accordionItem to *always* be that height, regardless of whether it was expanded.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication8.accordianDemo"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="400"
    xmlns:sdk2="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <sdk2:Accordion SelectionMode="ZeroOrMore" Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <sdk2:AccordionItem Header="Item 1" MaxHeight="150" Background="LightGoldenrodYellow">
                Hello World Row 1
            </sdk2:AccordionItem>
            <sdk2:AccordionItem Header="Item 2" MaxHeight="150" Background="LightGray">
                Hello World Row 2
            </sdk2:AccordionItem>
            <sdk2:AccordionItem Header="Item 3" Background="LightBlue">
                Hello World Row 3
            </sdk2:AccordionItem>
        </sdk2:Accordion>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the MaxHeight on the Content.  For now you have content as a `string` try making it a `ContentControl`

```
    <sdk2:Accordion SelectionMode="ZeroOrMore" Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <sdk2:AccordionItem Header="Item 1" Background="LightGoldenrodYellow">
            <ContentControl Content="Hello World Row 1" MaxHeight="150" />
        </sdk2:AccordionItem>
        <sdk2:AccordionItem Header="Item 2" Background="LightGray">
            <ContentControl Content="Hello World Row 2" MaxHeight="150" />
        </sdk2:AccordionItem>
        <sdk2:AccordionItem Header="Item 3" Background="LightBlue">
            <ContentControl Content="Hello World Row 3" />
        </sdk2:AccordionItem>
    </sdk2:Accordion>
```

Comment: That looked promising, but no.  It just ignored the max height in that case, and expanded each accordion item to fill all available space—which is much bigger than 150.  I've tried this with more robust content than just a string and the same thing happens.  This is just the simplest example I can come up with to demonstrate the problem

Comment: Sorry, this is because your VerticalAlignment is set to Stretch, you may have to write your own derived AccordionItem and handle the Measure/Arrange yourself.

Comment: Oh yeah - well maybe I'll change my UI so I don't *want* a fixed height on the first two items in the first place :)  Thanks, assuming nobody chimes in with a (simple) workaround I'll accept this

Comment: Ha - you're in NYC.  I'm headed back to the city for a much-needed vacation in a few weeks; I'm from upstate.  Anyway, enough SO spam.  Thanks again